# Best Practice to transform request headers before passing it to rest contoller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am working on a Spring Boot project with Java 11.

I have a rest controller that has a GET endpoint. The controller method takes account number as one of its arguments.

Account Number comes in as a request header.

Account number comes in as a 16 digit number. I have to use this account number to make another API call. However, this API expects account number to be in 20 digit format and hence I need to append 4 leading zeros every time.

Is there a best practice to do this transformation? I am thinking of creating a custom annotation and put it besides @RequestBody in the method argument.

For example -

public void getSampleData(@RequestBody @transform accountNumber) {…}

Comment: [There are no "best practices"](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/51674).  A so called "best practice" is merely someone's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

How about `String.format("%020d", accountNumber)`?

Best practice is to avoid problems, instead of trying to solve home-made problems.
Therefore I'd use an identical number-format on both sides; for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Best practice is not to use the phrase "best practice".  (To illustrate, >your< advice to avoid problems is a really good idea, but it is not going to be correct in all situations.  Which means that it it not "best practice".)

Comment: @StephenC I've rather meant that in terms of problem solving... because throwing complexity at a problem in most cases only makes it worse - and when the problem can be avoided altogether, this is usually the preferred option.

Comment: I know what you meant.  I don't disagree with your advice, but you shouldn't call it "best practice".  The term "best practice" is used by listeners as a way to avoid thinking, and by speakers as a short cut ... or as a way of expressing false authority.  The phrase should be dropped from our vocabulary ... IMO.

Comment: Or to put it another way: if "this is usually the preferred option" then it is literally not best practice.  Best practice means "always the best option".

Comment: @MartinZeitler I appreciate your advice but I am just a cog in the wheel. The client that I am working for has different app owners at both ends and they basically won’t sit together and solve this. I have no other option but to do this transformation so I was thinking of making it more elegant. Thank you for the feedback!